# OnResultExecuted() Code explain

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, events, controller, action-filter

In documentation it's said that:

> OnResultExecuted() - Is called after the action result that is returned by an action method is executed.

I don't understand what is meant by "after the action result is executed". Here is an example:

```
public class HomeController:BaseController {

//....
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var user = _repository.GetAllUsers();
    return View(@"~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml", user);
}

public ActionResult Suppliers()
{
     var suppliers = _repository.GetAllSuppliers();
     return PartialView(@"~/Views/Home/_Suppliers.cshtml",suppliers)
}

public ActionResult News()
{
     var news = _repository.GetAllNews();
     return PartialView(@"~/Views/Home/_News.cshtml",news)
}
// Other
```

The Index.cshtml view

```
@model IList<User>;
@{
   Layout=null;
 }

@Model.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name=="Mike")
</br>
@Html.Action("Suppliers","Home")  //action renders a simple partial no extra calls
</br>
@Html.Action("News","Home") //action renders a simple partial no extra calls
```

**QUESTION:**

At which point `OnResultExecuted()` will be called, assuming that is placed inside `BaseController`?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is that it is called after the view has been rendered... so basically, you can't change anything that has been executed in the view.

so it's more for logging type activities...

It would be executed in the following way:

```
OnActionExecuting.Home:Index

  OnActionExecuting.Home:Suppliers
  OnActionExecuted.Home:Suppliers

  OnActionExecuting.Home:News
  OnActionExecuted.Home:News

OnActionExecuted.Home:Index
```

So the misunderstanding is that the Suppliers and News actions are actually rendered within the Index method, and the Index method has not "Executed" until all the Actions defined in the View are actually rendered them self.

Comment: Your meditations seem to be close to mine. But when I'm trying to do some codework inside OnResultExecuted() relying on supposed behavior, something strange happens. It's been called for Suppliers method before the Index is rendered till the end.

Comment: I would imagine it gets called in the order : Suppliers, News, then Index... is that not happening?

Comment: Yes you are right. Please edit your answer and i'll mark it as an accepted. You deserved it